# Error when aura iteration given list property

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, iteration

I'm getting an error when I supply the list property acc.Contacts to the aura iteration component.

```
<aura:application>
    <aura:attribute name="acc" type="Account" 
        default="{ 
            'sobjectType': 'Account',
            'Contacts': [{'sobjectType': 'Contact', 'Name': 'test'}]
        }"
   />

    <aura:iteration items="{!v.acc.Contacts}" var="contact">
        <span>
            {!contact.Name}
        </span>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:application>
```

Result: "Something has gone wrong. [NoErrorObjectAvailable] Aura.loadComponent(): Failed to initialize application."

Is iterating over a list property not supported?

Comment: do you want to iterate a nested property (Contacts) in an object?

Comment: @Praveen yes I want to iterate over acc.Contacts

Comment: I contacted Salesforce support and they're looking into the issue. Their comment is: "This occurs because It appears that the default attribute on aura:attribute is creating a String value for non-String Collection types.
As another test, modifying the code to use a String Collection still including the default="" will work as expected.
<aura:attribute name="recentAccounts" type="String[]" default="" /> Works."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The work around I'm currently using is to assign acc.Contacts to a component attribute

```
<aura:application>
    <aura:attribute name="acc" type="Account" 
        default="{ 
            'sobjectType': 'Account',
            'Contacts': [{'sobjectType': 'Contact', 'Name': 'test'}]
        }"
    />
    <aura:attribute name="contacts" type="Contact[]" 
        default="{!v.acc.Contacts}"
    />

    <aura:iteration items="{!v.contacts}" var="contact">
        <span>
            {!contact.Name}
        </span>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your trying to do, but `type='Account'` maps to an sObject `Account` instance, and clearly it does not contains `Contacts` field/property.So changing the type to `Map` makes it to work.

```
<aura:attribute name="acc" type="Map" 
    default="{ 
    'sobjectType': 'Account',
        'Contacts': [{'sobjectType': 'Contact', 'Name': 'test'}]
    }"
/>
```

Comment: Using a map is great workaround thanks. I'm trying to iterate over the Contacts property. This is a valid property of an account object (this is valid Apex): List<Contact> contacts = [select (select Id from Contacts) from account limit 1].Contacts;

Comment: But it doesn't directly belong to Account object like other fields Name,Email,...so on. For ex: This is valid  `Account a = new Account(Name = 'test')`; not this  `Account a = new Account(Contacts = new Contact[]{new Contact(LastName='test')});`

Comment: Because `Contacts`  it is an special non-writable property returned by the SOQL query only, as far as i know.

Comment: I think it is still a property of an account object, it's just not a property that can be modified or set. Maybe it's just not readable in this context. That should be called out in the documentation though I think.